# android: How to update fragments in a timer

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer

I have a activity which has Tabbed fragments, I built the app using standard 3 tab fragment model.

The following code returns the inflated rootview tabs are pressed.

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
... public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

But If a tab is active how to update the contents from a timer  and where to put a timer in DummySectionFragment or mainActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the timer in the MainActivity and use getActivity().getCurrentTimerValue() to return the timer data. This would be the simplest method, if your project requirements are simple.

But if you need to update the UI in background continuously then, write a listener interface in MainActivity and implement it in DummySectionFragment.

Comment: Thanks lokesh, but a few points (a) How to write a listener interface (any example please)

Comment: Click on the links below [link 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and [link 2](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) should help you.

Comment: Thanks, I missed one imp fact, tabbed fragments. The DummySectionFragment onCreateView returns a rootview based on tab id. The rootview is inflated for each fragment xml. Now how to call a fragments methods now ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I stumbled across this when looking for a related problem, I thought it may help others if I provide what seems to be the most recommended solution for Activities and Fragments that need a simple timer. Hopefully you find this useful.

The basic concept is to post a message to a handler, which puts you on the UI thread by default, which is what you often need.

The basic, safe, catcher for posted events or messages look similar to this:

```
private static class DelayHandler extends Handler {
  private WeakReference<MyFragment> weak_fragment_reference;

  private DelayHandler(MyFragment frag) {
    weak_fragment_reference = new WeakReference<>(frag);
  }

  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    MyFragment frag = weak_fragment_reference.get();
    if (frag != null)
      frag.myDelayMethod();
  }
}
```

To setup a Delayed Message, you simply use one of the following methods:

- `handlerInstance.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(int what, long delayMillis)`
- `handlerInstance.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(int what, long uptimeMillis)`
- `handlerInstance.sendMessageDelayed(Message msg, long delayMillis)`
- `handlerInstance.sendMessageAtTime(Message msg, long uptimeMillis)`

Depending on your use case, it may also be useful to simply pass in a `Runnable` instead of putting your code in the handler. That gives you some options like `postAtTime(Runnable r, long uptimeMillis)` and `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`